# How to use IDialogService RequestClose When dialog window close button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

A usercontrol implement with IDialogAware in MVVM, when user control is closed by a OK button and this OK button is bind to viewmodel to call RequestClose?.Invoke(dialogResult),  dialog window is closed and call back function  is called;

```
_iDialogService.ShowDialog("View", new DialogParameters(""), CallBackResult=>
            {
              var test = CallBackResult;
            });
```

and CallBackResultis retrieved properly.

In this scenario, it works OK the CallBackResult has correctly

If user clicks close button  on the top of dialog  window, 
[Dialog Window Close Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knHb4.png)
RequestClose?.Invoke(dialogResult) is not called explicitly. the call back function is called but CallBackResult is empty.

I thought to use unloaded event to call RequestClose?.Invoke(dialogResult) is not called explicitly, in this case, RequestClose is null and throw exception

My question is how to pass dialog result to ShowDialog callback function if user click dialog close button on the top of pop up window.

Comment: I have no idea why Prism doesn't give us a view model-first dialog service... one could easily look at the view model after the dialog is closed.

Comment: can you be more specific on the answer.  It seems i have to use RequestClose  to pass the result Call back function

Comment: not an answer, probably not even a real comment, more of a rant :-D